# Want to redirect to new page using $routeProvider - angular js

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-ng-route

I have below code in app.config file.

```
 $routeProvider.when('/login', {
      templateUrl: 'login.html',
      controller : "LoginController"
    }).when('/', {
      templateUrl: 'assets/tpl/dashboard.html',
      controller : "MainController",
    /*  resolve: {
          loginRequired: loginRequired
      }*/
    }).when('/:folder/:tpl', {
      templateUrl: function(attr){
        console.log(attr.folder);
        console.log( attr.tpl);
        return 'assets/tpl/' + attr.folder + '/' + attr.tpl + '.html';
      }
    }).when('/:tpl', {
      templateUrl: function(attr){
        console.log(attr.tpl);
        return 'assets/tpl/' + attr.tpl + '.html';
      }
    }).otherwise({ redirectTo: '/' });
```

I want login route to work such that when I type projecturl/login then it take me to new page login.html instead of adding it to ng-view of dashboard.html.

Any guidance on this?

Comment: So you mean the login page is outside your angular app/context? It is an external application?

Comment: where is the route for `index.html`, your main route `/` points to `dashboard.html`

Comment: @nivas I have updated my question. It is dashboard.html and not index.html.

Comment: @devqon It is not an external application but a different html page.

Answer (score 0):

I see your html5mode is not set to true then you can access your login inside your dashboard at this url `projecturl/#/login` and before that make sure you have `<div ng-view></div>` or `<ng-view></ng-view>` whatever you prefer is declared somewhere inside your `dashboard.html`

Comment: I don't want to append it inside dashboard.html but I want to open a new page here.

Comment: Then you can try `projecturl/login` i think you will get the login page. Do you have a jsfiddle?